# How to assert not null subresource in Api-Platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have 2 entities:

```
class Act 
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Count(min=1)
     * @Assert\Valid(traverse=true)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ActItem", mappedBy="act", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $items;
}

class ActItem 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Act", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $act;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Type("float")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    private $count;
}
```

ActItem has **Assert\NotNull**, but when I try to create/update act with item like {count: null} then I get response:

```
hydra:description: "The type of the "count" attribute must be "float", "NULL" given."
```

I notice that if I remove @ORM\Column(type="float") then I get:

```
hydra:description: "items[0].count: This value should not be blank."
```

So why it working like this? How can i make it work in another order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact problem some time ago, apparently this is because your doctrine field is set as not `nullable`. (`@Assert\Type("float")`)

During runtime api-platform checks your Doctrine metadata and throws `InvalidArgumentException` if your data doesn't fit the criteria.
(I don't like this "feature" either, not sure why they're doing it).

To "fix" this you change your field to `@ORM\Column("float", nullable=true)`

It is also possible to override `api_platform.doctrine.orm.metadata.property.metadata_factory` service and change its behavior to ignore doctrine `nullable`.

Comment: I think you have mistake and you mean `@ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)`. It works in this case, but it's bad decision because it will make column nullable in database.

Comment: @AndrianovVasily Ah yes, typo there. fixed it.

And as you said, it is a bad idea, that's why I'm overriding the property metadata service for my projects to allow null values.